# Vsftp too much time for login

Tags: linux, centos, vsftpd, vsftp

While I'm trying to connect my new Vsftpd server using ftp client. The user authentication passed quit speedy but next steps lag too much.

Please help me to speedup my Vsftpd server.

Comment: Try speeding up the FTP server. That's all we can say with the information you provided. To get help, at least tell us exactly how you configured vsftpd.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable DNS resolution and connect to the server using the IP address. This could point to you if the DNS resolution is the culprit for the slowness.